# Schwartz Distribution Theory: (Non-)Surjectivity of $f \mapsto f*f$ in $ \mathcal E '$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

**For a compactly supported distribution $f$, I want to show the non-surjectivity of the map $H:f \mapsto f*f \in \mathcal{E}'$.**

---

My attempt: I have chosen to show that this is not the case by showing that $\text{image } (H)$ does not contain $ \delta_0'$. For instance I restrict myself to $d=1$.

Suppose that $H$ is surjective. Applying the Fourier transform on the convolution, I get
$(\hat{f}(z)) ^2 = i z$. The theorem of Paley-Wiener-Schwartz guarantees that $(\hat{f}(z)) $ should be an entire function. However, as it is well-known, no such entire function exists:

If this were true, then $e^{i \pi /4}\hat{f}(z)$ would be the square root function, which cannot be well defined on $\mathbb C$, and even less so entire.

---

Q1: Is there another way of achieving the result (i.e. with a choice significantly different than $\delta_0'$, and with an approach different than the one using the Fourier transform)?

Q2: Can I generalize this without much effort in the case of $d \ge 1$ (probably using the tensor product)?

---

Edit: The source is [an exam at Lund University [problem 3]](http://www.ctr.maths.lu.se/media/MATP11/2017vt2017/tent.jun14.pdf).

Comment: Q1: I don't think that there is any easier solution than yours.

Comment: Q2: I think that it should not be very difficult, but not trivial, to generalize the solution to $d > 1$.

Comment: Being a Swede, I'm wonder if you study in Lund or if you just found their old exams online?

Comment: @md2perpe  I actually study in France (Orsay) but found the exam by chance while looking at their courses.

Comment: Then it was my second alternative. Nice anyway to see references to Sweden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the only reasonable answer. The generalization can be achieved because Paley-Wiener-Schwartz applies to functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$.