# Show that $\{ f \ast f: f \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n) \} \subsetneq \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: distribution-theory, fourier-transform

I wonder if somebody could help me understand the following solution:

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $F=\{ f \ast f: f \in \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n) \} \subset \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Show that $F \neq \mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ($f\ast f$ is the convolution of $f$ with it self and $\mathcal{E'} $ is the space of distributions with compact support in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Assume the contrary. Then $\delta_1 -\delta_0 \in F$ so there is an $f \in \mathcal{E'}$ such that $f \ast f= \delta_1 -\delta_0$
Since $f \in \mathcal{E'}$ such the Fourier transform of $f$, $\hat{f}$, is complex analytic. Then $ (\hat{f}(\xi))^2= e^{-i\xi}-1 \in \mathcal{O}({\xi}) \implies \hat{f}(0)=0$.

I fail to see why this is a contradiction (also I don't get the last implication). Does anybody understand this?

Comment: The last implication: Set $\xi=0$ in $(\hat{f}(\xi))^2= e^{-i\xi}-1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335033/schwartz-distribution-theory-non-surjectivity-of-f-mapsto-ff-in-mathca

Comment: I am a bit rusty but I believe this to be the case because there exists no non-constant entire function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$ and such that $g$ admits a square root. Remember that, if entire, $g$ is an open map so its image contains a neighborhood of $0$.